# php woocommerce if statement with attributes not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code on my woocommerce shop page.

```
function uit_productie_badge() {
   global $product;
    $beschikbaarheid = $product->get_attribute('pa_beschikbaarheid');
    echo '<span class="sold-out">' . $beschikbaarheid . '</span>';
    if ($beschikbaarheid = "dsgdfsg"){
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'uit_productie_badge');
```

The `span` with the badge is showing with the attribute value, however, the if statement is not working. 
`dsgdfsg` is just random text and should not be in there, however, each product shows the `Hello World!`. How can I solve this?

Comment: With single  `=`, you will declare a variable. With two `=` you compare the value of a string. Check a post below from Sam Swift.

Comment: Voting to close as simply typographical error....

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is this line;

```
if ($beschikbaarheid = "dsgdfsg"){
```

Using a single equals is variable assignment as apposed to checking if it matches, if you use 2 it will work, so this will fix;

```
if ($beschikbaarheid == "dsgdfsg"){
```

For example, if you have the following function;

```
function AssignTo()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['variable']) && $_SESSION['variable'] == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could do the following;

```
if ($a = AssignTo())
{
    // The function returned true, so the check is true and $a is set to true
}
else
{
    // The function returned false, so the check fails and $a is set to false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this question actually should be voted-to-close as a "simple typographical error".

Comment: Well, yes and no IMO, it is a simple typographical error yes, but OP still had an issue, though I do agree with the closure of the question